# Setting property by Ref while converting Type if needed

Tags: c#, properties, typeof

I have a complex series of classes, I put here a minimal example which compiles and works:

```
public class DataClass : IMPropertyAsStringSettable
{
    public int num { get; set; }
    public string code { get; set; }
    public PartClass part { get; set; }
    public MemberClass member { get; set; }
    public DataClass()
    {
        part = new PartClass();
        member = new MemberClass();
    }
}
public class PartClass : IMPropertyAsStringSettable
{
    public int seriesNum { get; set; }
    public string seriesCode { get; set; }
}
public class MemberClass : IMPropertyAsStringSettable
{
    public int versionNum { get; set; }
    public SideClass side { get; set; }
    public MemberClass()
    { 
        side = new SideClass();
    }
}
public class SideClass : IMPropertyAsStringSettable
{
    public string firstDetail { get; set; }
    public string secondDetail { get; set; }
    public bool include { get; set; }
}
```

The interface that you see, is implemented as follows in same namespace as all:

```
public interface IMPropertyAsStringSettable { }

public static class PropertyAsStringSettable
{
    public static void SetPropertyAsString(this IMPropertyAsStringSettable self, string propertyName, string value)
    {
        var property = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(self)[propertyName];
        var convertedValue = property.Converter.ConvertFrom(value);
        property.SetValue(self, convertedValue);
    }
}
```

I am trying to achieve setting a property value sort of 'by ref', meaning, by actually calling the name of the property as from a string.
I am trying but can't get work out two problems. I can't set the 'linked' properties values, or something in the implementation doesn't work as it should because of my mistake in the interface.
And second and equally important, i can't read and convert the property, i.e. I only have strings as values, and sometimes the properties are bool, int, double, DateTime etc.
Now, I know that conversion is a big subject, so I thought to try to read the property type and do a conversion by try/catch but I couldn't.

This is what I am trying to achieve (based on the above piece of code):

```
        static int Main(string[] args)
    {
        //just initializing the whole thing without
        //setting values to properties
        DataClass myClass = new DataClass()
        {
            part = new PartClass(),
            member = new MemberClass()
            {
                side = new SideClass()
            }
        };

        // here I read from a source names and values.....

        //and I am trying to populate like this:

        myClass.SetPropertyAsString("include", "true"); //this property is in SideClass, and also a bool
        myClass.SetPropertyAsString("seriesNum", "88"); //this property is in PartClass and an int..
```

To use directly as:

```
        //This should print "True"
        Console.WriteLine("myClass member side include = " + myClass.member.side.include.ToString());

        Console.ReadKey();
        return 0;
    }
```

I really hope someone could help, I'm no expert on that; if you could provide a working piece of code based on the above, I would appreciate a lot. Thank you all

Note: using reflection could work better (trying to assign values to all properties as I found them in a JSON string). Any help welcome..

Comment: That interface is empty which is something you should avoid at first place. ANother thing what I am not getting is what exactly you are trying to achieve or what is the reason you are trying to do it this way. Can you explain what is what you want to achieve, please? Maybe there will be simpler way to get it work.

Comment: @John Thank you for your input. I am trying to achieve the `myClass.SetPropertyAsString("include", "true");` So, I do have a json string that I have to read and it matches perfectly the structure of the classes you see above. So I am trying to read json `"side": "true"` and then find this property in the classes and set it to true, and so on and so forth. The problem is, I first have to see where is that property (could be not directly in the first class but in a 'linked' class as in the example) and then try to assign the value using SetValue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use reflection?

To set:

```
var type = self.GetType();
var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
var convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, property.PropertyType);
property.SetValue(self, convertedValue);
```

To get:

```
public T GetPropertyValue<T>(this IYourInterface self, string name) 
{
   var type = self.GetType();
   var property = type.GetProperty(propertyName);
   return (T) property.GetValue(self);
}
```

I do not understand well why would you actually want to do this, it seems really strange, the problem seems like it could be resolved with serialisation to a standard format, like JSON. Maybe you should look into that.

Answer (score 0):

If the property isn't a top-level one, then we need the path that lead to the target property, in our case the path is `member:side:include`. I'm using here `:` as the delimiter.

```cs
//top-level property
myClass.SetPropertyAsString("num", "88");

//nested properties
myClass.SetPropertyAsString("member:side:include", "true");
myClass.SetPropertyAsString("part:seriesNum", "15");
```

Then modify the reflection code so it can go down a given path:

```cs
//will handle both nested and top-level properties
public static void SetPropertyAsString(this IMPropertyAsStringSettable self, string propertyName, string value) {
    //current, is in a way, the property iterator
    var current = self;

    var keys = propertyName.Split(":");

    //iterate over keys till the key before last -since the last key is the target property-
    foreach (var key in keys[0..^1]) {
        var property = current.GetType().GetProperty(key);
        current = property.GetValue(current) as IMPropertyAsStringSettable;
    }

    var targetProperty = current.GetType().GetProperty(keys.Last());

    //convert the input value to the data type of the target property, and set it to the target property
    targetProperty.SetValue(current, Convert.ChangeType(value, targetProperty.PropertyType));
}
```

---

**EDIT: for C# < 8.0**

Based on your comments, you're using C# version < 8.0 where some of the features used in the original response aren't available (like the range operator `^`). I have compiled the following on `.NET 4.7.2`, `C# 7.3` and produced the same result.

```cs
public static void SetPropertyAsString(this IMPropertyAsStringSettable self, string propertyName, string value) {
    var current = self;
    var keys = propertyName.Split(':');
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.Length - 1; i++) {
        var property = current.GetType().GetProperty(keys[i]);
        current = property.GetValue(current) as IMPropertyAsStringSettable;
    }
    var targetProperty = current.GetType().GetProperty(keys[keys.Length - 1]);
    targetProperty.SetValue(current, Convert.ChangeType(value, targetProperty.PropertyType));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I have tried but seems can't make it - in `var keys = propertyName.Split(":");` throws cannot convert from string to char (same for the `var property = current.GetType().GetProperty(key);` for the `key`..). I tried to give additional argument `StringSplitOptions.None` but still throws same error..  also, in the foreach, at `keys[0..^ 1])` does not recognize the `.^` ("identifier expected").

Comment: Could you help a bit with the above? seems your solution could work.. thank you!

Comment: @Nick You're welcome! I have updated my answer with a version that doesn't utilize `C# 8.0` features.

Comment: Thank you very much, please help me in a small thing, it returns Object reference not set to an instance of the object, with a reference of the error to line of `current = property.GetValue(current) as IMPropertyAsStringSettable;` and about a `d__2.MoveNext()` which I don't really understand... Could you help me?

Comment: Here is a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/CUtgfm) of the working code. Without the full exception message and possibly a debugger, it's hard to tell, but I would assume the error is caused by the input (how you are calling the function and forming the path i.e. the path doesn't match the properties names), or maybe create a new question with additional details.